# Retrieving shell script exit code (return value)

Tags: c#, .net, logstash, sh

Trying to validate a Logstash config file. When running the following line from a Windows command line:

`C:> C:\Logstash\bin\logstash -t -f C:\Logstash\config\my.config`

I can then check the result using

`echo %errorlevel%`

which returns 1 in case of a syntax error. Now I want to do this programatically in C#, so:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

var logstashProcess = Process.Start(@"C:\Logstash\bin\logstash", @"-t -f C:\Logstash\config\my.config");
logstashProcess.WaitForExit();
return logstashProcess.ExitCode == 0;
```

The problem is that it always returns true (exit code is zero) - even when the config file is totally messed up.

My guess: since `C:\Logstash\bin\logstash` is a shell script, the zero I get is the shell itself running successfully - not the Logstash process (which is executed from within that script using jruby). Any idea on how to get the real return value? Will a batch file work? (I prefer not to add an extra script to the party at this point)